# send all traffic for /v2/* to same file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to code an updated version of my site.

To do this I'm just doing it all in a new repo, which is DOMAIN/v2/.

I have a single php file which should control all the routing, so any request starting with /v2/ should use this file.

currently my .htaccess rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule    ^v2/?$    /v2/php/init.php    [NC,L]    # V2 - all routes handled here
```

this works fine for the exact route /v2 , but as soon as I try and go to /v2/jobs it hits my 404 rule instead:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /php/404.php
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this(where `path` is the rest of the url after `v2`):

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^v2/(.*)$ /v2/php/init.php?path=$1   [QSA,L]
```

It sends all requests to the `v2` folder to `/v2/php/init.php` if the file doesn't exist.